# Box API OAuth2.0 in script

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, redirect, box, boxapiv2

I am writing a script to automate the process of regularly upload specific files to Box.

After reading the BOX API, I know I have to use client-id and client-secret to get an authentication url which open in browser, then I login in by username and password, click allow, then I get redirect to a url I provided with Auth Code attached to the end of this redirect url.

problem now is, I am writing a script not an web or mobile app. Therefore, I have to avoid these UI web html manual login.

Is there a way??? I can get this authentication url by code in python using BOX's python SDK.Then I can open a browser in python by webbrowser module then I can type in username/password. Then I get redirected. Maybe I can use some special redirect url to send auth code back to my code? I don't know how to do that.

Please help!

Comment: You could start a local webserver and redirect the user to that server (i.e. localhost).

Answer (score 0):

You should use JWT authentication.

> Unlike the standard OAuth 2 flow, JWT will allow you to use your own identity 
>   provider to bypass the application auth and redirect. Building with JWT will allow 
>   you to hide the Box process behind the scenes.

[Authenticate with JWT](https://developer.box.com/docs/authenticate-with-jwt)